# Date picker issue in xamarin forms ios application

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a xamarin forms application which is a cross-platform where it should work in android, ios and uwp. We have a datepicker in our project. Once we open the date picker and select the date it should display it in the datepicker box.

Code:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePickerControl" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Date="{Binding FromDate}" Style="{StaticResource Body2/Black}"
                 IsVisible="{Binding FromDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeNullOrEmptyBoolConverter}}"
                 behaviours:CommonEntryBehaviour.ApplyTransparentBGEffect="True">
                 <DatePicker.Behaviors>
                    <behaviours:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="DateSelected"/>
                 </DatePicker.Behaviors>
      </DatePicker>
```

Now the issue is in android and uwp it is working fine. But in ios while selecting the date in the date picker it is showing the date in the text box with the first two characters cutting. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your style?

Comment: Could you please post the complete code so that we can reproduce the issue first ?

Comment: Hi I have added horizontaloptions=fillandexpand to the date picker and it is working now :)